# Blocking a user from logging in with a certain permission level and then an alert displaying to let them know why

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, permissions

I am trying to figure out how to block a user from signing in to my site unless they are over a certain permission level. I am making my site public and once someone registers they are given the permission level 'bench'. Once I accept the user and change the permission level, then they are able to login. The way I am blocking the 'bench' permission level users is with a redirect to the index page(where they sign in at). However, I want to display some sort of alert that pop's up displaying a message that I create and then from the start not even allow that user to move forward.

I'm not sure if I can do this with validation or not. Something like if this user tries to log in, the script dies once it sees that the permission level is at the group 'bench'. Then a pop alert displays saying why.

This is how I allow the user to login..

```
if(Input::exists()) {
if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array('required' => true),
        'password' => array('required' => true)
    ));

    if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();

        $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
        $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

        if($login) {
            Redirect::to('userIndex.php');
        } else {
            $tryagain = '<span class="signinpanel">' . "The information you entered did not match our records." . '</span>';
        }

    } else {
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

I then redirect like this...

```
if($user->hasPermission('bench')) {
header("Location: http://sundayfundayleague.com");
die();
}
```

This is my permissions code:

```
public function hasPermission($key) {
    $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));

 if($group->count()) {
        $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

        if($permissions[$key] == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I go about doing this?

UPDATE:

I am not sure I am doing this correctly. I'm doing a die with it and showing an error message I made up.

```
if(Input::exists()) {
if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    $permissionError = "Your membership request has not been accepted yet.";

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array('required' => true),
        'password' => array('required' => true)

        if($user->hasPermission('bench')) {
        die($permissionError);
    ));

    if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();

        $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
        $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

        if($login) {
            Redirect::to('userIndex.php');
        } else {
            $tryagain = '<span class="signinpanel">' . "The information you entered did not match our records." . '</span>';
        }

    } else {
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could handle it in the index page: `header("Location: http://sundayfundayleague.com?error=benched_user");`. Now you can check for an error and display a message as a pop up or on top of the screen or whatever.

Comment: The only thing is, I redirect back to the index page on the logged in page called userIndex. You can see how I do that here...  if($login) {
            Redirect::to('userIndex.php');
        } else {
            $tryagain = '<span class="signinpanel">' . "The information you entered did not match our records." . '</span>';
        }

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just add 'permission' as a criteria for login? And if the permission is not met, the form restarts and displays a message saying "waiting for approval" or what not. So when logging in, you check if the user has the right permission, and if not, you display the message you want.
If the user is new and signing up, you add their information to the db, but keep the permission to 'bench' and you do not log them in, instead you refresh the form and display the message you need.
(If I understood the situation correctly)

Comment: So you are basically saying I should add the permission levels into my validation and if it meets the requirement to allow them to continue? I'm honestly not even sure how I would configure the permissions into my validation. I have different levels of permissions (each with a different id). 'bench' is id 1 and it goes to 5. Bench is the only one not allowed to log in.

Comment: @Paul Yes that's what I was thinking. Just like the error messages saying "Wrong username or password", instead it can also check for user permission level, and display an appropriate message if criteria not met.
Basically if (ID == 1) --> refresh and display message. The same way as if password is wrong, it displays a message I assume.

Comment: @Amrito10 I updated my question with an attempt at doing this. I don't believe I am doing this correctly. Is this the way you would do it or how would you change that?

Comment: I'm getting an unexpected if syntax error for the line I added in with my permission line. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home4/pfarley1/public_html/sundayfundayleague.com/index.php on line 13

Comment: @Paul Well for instance there isn't a closing bracket for the if statement (on line 13)

Comment: I fixed that and put if($user->hasPermission('bench')) {
        die($permissionError);.....above the.. if($validation->passed code.... I got this error.....Fatal error: Call to a member function hasPermission() on a non-object in /home4/pfarley1/public_html/sundayfundayleague.com/index.php on line 11